# Circular dependencies - Exercise from Eloquent Javascript book

Tags: javascript, module

I am trying to understand how this code works: (It is this exercise from the Eloquent Javascript book. http://eloquentjavascript.net/10_modules.html#i_E/zWqBFdy8)

```js
require.cache = Object.create(null);

function require(name) {
  if (!(name in require.cache)) {
    let code = readFile(name);
    let module = {exports: {}};
    require.cache[name] = module;
    let wrapper = Function("require, exports, module", code);
    wrapper(require, module.exports, module);
  }
  return require.cache[name].exports;
}

// Example:

// a.js
const {b} = require('./b');
console.log(b);
exports.a = 'a';

// b.js
const {a} = require('./a');
console.log(a);
exports.b = 'b';
```

The book states that: "Many module systems simply forbid this (Circular dependencies) because whichever order you choose for loading such modules, you cannot make sure that each module’s dependencies have been loaded before it runs."

And the solution is: "Require adds modules to its cache before it starts loading the module. That way, if any require call made while it is running tries to load it, it is already known, and the current interface will be returned, rather than starting to load the module once more."

I am having trouble understanding what is meant by the order of module loading
and why we are not sure if dependencies are loaded, since the code is synchronous. Ultimately I am not sure how the code in the two modules I added as an example interact.